# Specify how primary keys are generated while importing XML using SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis

I am trying to import a complex XML using SSIS. It creates the primary key using the node index, so if I import xml with different data but same structure, it will duplicate the keys. If I provide the primary key as identity, it doesn't reference to the foreign keys.

My problem is exactly as specified here [Specify how primary keys are generated during SSIS XML import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697533/specify-how-primary-keys-are-generated-during-ssis-xml-import/47038815?noredirect=1#comment81024112_47038815)

I cannot afford any manual process as there are 100+ tables. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
<Account SalesTerritory="T1" SalesDivision="D1">
  <Address Zip="12345" State="MO" City="ST LOUIS"/>
  <Order Amount="100" Date="08/29/17"></>
</Account>
```

Assume simplified XML above.

SSIS package creates AccountID=1 in Account table, AddressId=2 in Address table and OrderId=3 in Order table. Basically it takes **NODE INDEX**. Now, assume I import **same structured XML**, but with different data, still it creates same IDs. I want it to create different IDs.

Now, If I use the ID of Identity created by MSSQL, the SSIS won't reference it as Foreign Key in the reference table.

Comment: A simplified example would be helpful.

Comment: @Brian please check the updated question. I have added example.